# Use specific value in loop while reactive

Tags: r, shiny

I am generating 3 valueboxes based on a for loop like so;

```
for ( i in 0:3) {
  name = as.character(i)

  output[[name]] <- ({
    renderValueBox(
      valueBox(value = i,
               icon = "fa-euro")
    )
  })
}
```

As the value, for this example, I would display i and would like to have it display 1, 2, 3 when I call it like so;

````
###
```{r}
valueBoxOutput("0")
```

###
```{r}
valueBoxOutput("1")
```

###
```{r}
valueBoxOutput("2")
```
````

However, because it's reactive and i is 3 at the moment of rendering, I will not have that, I will have 3 valueboxes displaying 3. The end goal here is to have 3 valueboxed based on reactively loaded dataframe, like so;

```
set_aggregated <- reactiveFileReader(1000, session,  "./rdsdata/set_aggregated.rds", readRDS)
```

And then call the different values in there like so;

```
  output[[name]] <- ({
    renderValueBox(
      valueBox(value = hub_set_aggregated()[i, "code"],
               color = ddy_colour_4,
               icon = "fa-euro")
    )
  })
```

I think I understand why it's not working. But don't know how to get it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be safer to use a function that creates a proper closure rather than doing it directly in a loop. For example

```
rvb <- function(i) {
  force(i)
  renderValueBox(valueBox(value = i, icon = "fa-euro"))
}

for ( i in 0:3) {
  name = as.character(i)
  output[[name]] <- rvb(i)
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Is it the force(i) that does it?

Comment: The force() helps to avoid lazy evaluation. It needs to work in a function scope, because for loops don’t create their own scope, you can’t use force() inside a for loop.